# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uri

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, wcf-binding, livecycle

I get the following error when I am trying to invoke my Adobe Livecyle Soap service:

Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uri

The strange thing is that I don't have any parameter named "uri". I can't debug this error since the service can't even start. The error message is all I've got.

Here is the code, that I pass the parameter:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = 
    new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;

LetterService.LETTER_APPLICATIONS_Client client = 
    new LetterService.LETTER_APPLICATIONS_Client(
          binding, 
          new EndpointAddress(
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]));
```

Comment: You'll have to show your code. The error means that a method you call has been passed a value of null for its 'uri' parameter.

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details. This is very useful if you want to share code, because you can use the `{}` button to format it - you can't do a decent job of code formatting in comments. The edit link is at the bottom left under the tags.

Comment: And it's almost certainly the `EndpointAddress` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404972.aspx) that's throwing the exception - check your config file and make sure that you have a "LetterMergeURL" `appSetting`.

Comment: Uniform resource identifier (URI) is used to identify a website or resource so this is a strong indicator that your error is in part of your code which points to such a resource. This should give you a good idea on where to look to debug your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parameter to `EndpointAddress()` is named `URI` (You can place your cursor just after the `(`, and press `Ctrl + Shift + Space` to see the parameter list).

You could verify that this is the problem by replacing:

```
new EndpointAddress(
            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]));
```

..With something like the following:

```
new EndpointAddress("http://your.service.uri/");
```

If that works, you know your error is config-related.

Comment: That solved the problem, it is all about the config-file. Thank you for the answer.